# How to manipulate DOM elements,and replace it in chrome extension script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

In chrome extension,how to manipulate original html content

> index.html

```
  <div class='demo'>
    <SPAN class ="number">1</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">2</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">3</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">4</SPAN>
    </div>
```

> content.js

```
//some logic to get arrays of text in "number" class from html,then multiply with 2 , then update the index.html
```

> required output (index.html)

```
  <div class='demo'>
    <SPAN class ="number">2</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">4</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">6</SPAN>
<SPAN class ="number">8</SPAN>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this help you

> index.html

```
 <div class='demo'>
<span  class ="number">1</span>
<span  class ="number">2</span>
<span  class ="number">3</span>
<span  class ="number">4</span>
    </div>
    <button>d</button>
```

> content.js

```
$("button").click(function(){

    x=document.getElementsByClassName("number");  // Find the elements
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
var y = parseInt(x[i].innerText) * 2;
x[i].innerText= y;    // Change the content

} 
});
```

This will give you desired output,

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple jquery code.

```
var c = 2;
$(".demo .number").each(function(){
    $(this).html(c);
    c += 2;
});
```